# What is the difference between JavaScript class definitions styles?

Tags: javascript

I am not clear on the actual difference between these two styles of "class" definitions in JavaScript.

Method a:

`function myclass() {}`

Method b:

```
myclass = function() {}
```

Is there any difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are functions, the first one is a *function declaration*, the second is a variable assignment with a *function expression*.

The main difference is that the function declarations are *hoisted* up in the current scope at parse time, they behave like if you declared them at the top of its enclosing scope.

The grammar of both is very similar, the only grammatical difference is that the name *function expressions* is optional, the parser knows which one you are using based on the "context" where you use it, e.g. your first example is a *function declaration* because the function itself is defined on a `Program` (technically a place outside of any function, in the global scope), or in `FunctionBody` (inside a function).

A *function expression* is created when it is evaluated itself in *expression context*, e.g.:

```
function foo () {} // function declaration
(function foo() {}); // function expression
```

In the above example the second one is interpreted as a function expression because is surrounded by parentheses, and parentheses can only hold *expressions*...

I highly recommend you the following in-depth article about the topic:

- [Named function expressions demystified](http://yura.thinkweb2.com/named-function-expressions/)

Answer (score 2):

The latter is a closure which you are assigning to a variable. As soon as the variable is deleted (or is assigned a different value) you won't be able to call the function anymore. Besides that both are pretty much the same as functions are first class citizens in Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you're defining functions, not classes.

Secondly, the second definition will put the `myclass` into the global namespace, whereas the first will not (it would be defined in function scope instead). However, so far as I'm aware, the following are roughly equivalent:

```
function myclass() {}
```

and

```
var myclass = function() {}
```

There are some small differences, which are [explored over on developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Functions). Having said that, I've never noticed any of the differences.

Comment: The first one has a `name` property of `myclass` and also is moved completely to the top of the function as opposed to how only the initiation of vars is sent to the top.

Answer (score 0):

In the second case, you are declaring the function as a variable. It is particularly useful for something like this in OOP:

```
var myObject = new Object();
myObject.add = function(a,b) {
    return a + b;
};  
myObject.add(1, 2);
```